# How to upgrade file system from mke2fs 1.42.13 to mke2fs 1.43-WIP?

Tags: 16.04, apt, filesystem

I use this command to figure out the mkefs version on my Ubuntu 16.04:

```
sudo mkfs.ext4 -V
```

It gives this output:

```
mke2fs 1.42.13 (17-May-2015)
    Using EXT2FS Library version 1.42.13
```

This output is different from another system:

```
mke2fs 1.43-WIP (15-Mar-2016)
    Using EXT2FS Library version 1.43-WIP
```

How can I upgrade this mke2fs?  I try sudo apt-get but no package is found under that name.  Thanks.

Comment: Is the other system also Ubuntu 16.04 ? And are they both updated to the same level ?

Comment: It is in `e2fsprogs` package. Ubuntu 16.04 LTS has [1.42.13-1ubuntu1, but 1.43 is in zesty, artful and bionic](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&exact=1&searchon=names&keywords=e2fsprogs). Why you need 1.43 version?

Comment: I see.  I was following a guide, and didn't know about this arrangement.  I am new to Linux.